# JSON beginner: (can I/how can I/should I) automatically convert a clean JSON array into many SQL tables in a particular way?

Tags: mysql, json

**Background:** I am a JSON beginner and advanced-beginner SQL user. I am trying to learn how to parse JSON using MySQL, and I came up with the following problem to try to solve. This might be a stupid thing to want to do--let me know.

**Terminology:** As I understand it, I can refer to everything in between a pair of curly braces ("{..}") as an "object," and every pair of things separated by a ":" as a "key-value pair," and everything in between a pair of brackets ("[..]") as an "array." That's the terminology I'll use below, but if that's wrong then I will change it.

**Problem:** This question has a lot of potentially incorrect assumptions built into it. I want to start with a JSON array and do the following things. **(Can I/should I/how can I) do this?**

1. Convert every array of the form [a,b,c,...] into an object of the
   form {"1":a,"2":b,"3":c,...}, including arrays that are inside of
   other objects or arrays. (Except don't do this to the outermost
   array.)
2. For every key whose value is sometimes an object and sometimes not an object, convert all of its associated "non-object" values x
   into objects of the form {"genericvalue" : x}.
3. Find a string that is never used as a key within the JSON file; call it f.
4. To every object, add a key-value pair equal to "f" : i, where i is an integer such that no two objects have the same key-value pair "f" : i. (Trying to create some kind of unique identifier.)
5. Define a "key path" as a sequence of keys {k_1,k_2,k_3...k_n} such that the value associated with k_1 is an object containing k_2, the value associated with k_2 is an object containing k_3, and so on. Enumerate all "key paths" associated with the JSON file.
6. For each "key path," do the following:

   1. If this key path never has an associated key-value pair whose value is an object, don't make a table.
   2. If this key path always has an associated key-value pair whose value is an object, make a table with one column for each key that appears in any of the objects associated with this key path, plus another column called f_parent.
   3. I think the above should be the only possibilities, because of step 2.
7. For each object o, create a row in the table associated with its key path with the following field values:

   1. If o is nested inside another object, the "f_parent" column should be equal to the value associated with the key "f" in the object containing o. Otherwise, the "f" column should be null.
   2. For all of the other columns {k_1,k_2,...k_n}, the column should be a) null if k_n is not a key that appears within o, or it should be equal to the value associated with k_n if k_n is a key
      that appears within o.

**Example:** I want to start with a JSON array like this:

```
[
  {
    "color": "pink",
    "flavor": "strawberry",
    "ingredients": {
      "1": "strawberries",
      "2": "chemical x"
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "green",
    "flavor": "pancake",
    "tags": [
      "breakfast",
      "green"
    ]
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "flavor": "pumpkin spice",
    "price": 3,
    "ingredients": {
      "0": "pumpkin",
      "1": "spice"
    },
    "tags": "seasonal"
  }
]
```

Let's set f equal to "recordid". After steps 1-3, I think I want it to look like this:

```
[
  {
    "recordid" : 1,
    "color": "pink",
    "flavor": "strawberry",
    "ingredients": {
      "recordid" : 2,
      "1": "strawberries",
      "2": "chemical x"
    }
  },
  {
    "recordid" : 3,
    "color": "green",
    "flavor": "pancake",
    "tags": {
      "recordid" : 4,
      "1":"breakfast",
      "2":"green"
    }
  },
  {
    "recordid" : 5,
    "color": "red",
    "flavor": "pumpkin spice",
    "price": 3,
    "ingredients": {
      "recordid" : 6,
      "0": "pumpkin",
      "1": "spice"
    },
    "tags": {
      "recordid" : 7,
      "genericvalue":"seasonal"
    }
  }
]
```

So basically the array of tags for green pancake has been turned into an object, the single "seasonal" tag for red pumpkin spice has been turned into an object, and everything now has a record id.

Then I want to make the following tables:

- "flavors" (I made this up); this is the table associated with the empty "key path"; the fields would be

  - recordid_parent (always null)
  - recordid
  - color
  - flavor
  - ingredients
  - tags
- "flavors.tags"; the fields would be

  - recordid_parent
  - recordid
  - genericvalue
  - 1
  - 2
- "flavors.ingredients"; the fields would be

  - recordid_parent
  - recordid
  - 1
  - 2
  - 0

The "flavors.ingredients" table would look like this:

| recordid_parent | recordid | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | strawberries | chemical x | null |
| 5 | 6 | null | spice | pumpkin |

The "flavors.tags" table would look like this:

| recordid_parent | recordid | 1 | 2 | genericvalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | breakfast | green | null |
| 5 | 7 | null | null | seasonal |

The "flavors" table would look like this:

| recordid_parent | recordid | color | flavor | price | ingredients | tags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | 1 | pink | strawberry | null | (JSON object) | (JSON object) |
| null | 3 | green | pancake | null | (JSON object) | (JSON object) |
| null | 5 | red | pumpkin spice | 3 | (JSON object) | (JSON object) |

(I didn't fill in all of the "(JSON object)" stuff).

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you expect to this question! Mysql does have some json functions, but lacks the dynamic enumeration of arrays and lists, so I would not start implementing this feature in mysql

Comment: Thanks @Shadow! "No, you can't do that, sorry" or "Yes, you can do that, but only with a bunch of stupid loops and string parsing and it still might not cover weird cases" are definitely in the list of answers that I'm expecting. If you answer that, I'll accept it.